# JMockit: How to override already mocked method with a new mock?

Tags: java, mocking, jmockit

I think I might have found a bug in JMockit, but I would like some to confirm whether it's a bug or there's something I'm missing.

I have the following (very simple) class:

```java
public class Dummy {
    public void foo() {System.out.println("O");}
}
```

Now I have the following tests, where in each of them I try to mock the method 'foo' more than once (each test does it a little differently):

Test #1

```java
@Test
public void test1() {

    new MockUp<Dummy>() {

        @Mock
        public void foo(Invocation inv) {

            System.out.println("A");
            inv.proceed();
        }
    }

    new MockUp<Dummy>() {

        @Mock
        public void foo(Invocation inv) {

            System.out.println("B");
            inv.proceed();
        }
    }

    new Dummy().foo();
}
```

Test #2

```java
@Test
public void test2() {

    mock("A");
    mock("B");
    new Dummy().foo();
}

private void mock(final String s) {

    new MockUp<Dummy>() {

        @Mock
        public void foo(Invocation inv) {

            System.out.println(s);
            inv.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between the tests is the extraction of the mock code to a different method. But the results are not the same...

Test #1 output:

```
B
A
B
O
```

This is odd, because I wouldn't expect A to appear at all. But anyway, here's test #2 output:

```
B
A
A
A
...ad infinitum
```

Test #2 will fail with a StackOverflowError.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Update (with the solution)**

As @Rogério mentioned, this behavior is not acceptable.
Then how can the mock be overridden? like this:

```java
private MockUp<Dummy> mock;

@Test
public void test3() {

        mockCorrectly("A");
        mockCorrectly("B");
        new Dummy().foo();
}


private void mockCorrectly(final String s) {

    if (mock != null) {
        mock.tearDown();
    }

    mock = new MockUp<Dummy> {

        @Mock
        public void foo(Invocation inv) {

            System.out.println(s);
            inv.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

And for the output:

```
B
O
```

Great :)

Comment: Have you had any success using top-level MockUp classes with @Injectable?  I am unable to get top-level MockUp classes to autowire into my test classes no matter what I've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly happens here; apparently, at runtime some "chained mocking" is occurring.

The real problem is that both tests are doing something invalid with the `MockUp` API: they are mocking the *same* method in the same class twice in the same test. It is ok to have two different mock-ups for the same class in the same test, as long as they mock *different* methods/constructors.

The resulting behavior is undefined, as JMockit does not support multiple simultaneous mockings of the same method.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to mock an object's method and override it? I find that feature essential, because I mock one of the methods in my class in a certain way on 'setUp' (@Before), but then on some specific tests I want to have a different behavior for that method.

Comment: I think I found an answer for that. I'll edit the question with the solution.